# Qml with static build

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qtdeclarative

I've seen a lot of topics about this problem but none can actually solve my problem. When I create a new Qt Quick application with `QtQuick 2.4` I have the error:

> Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: quick qml

If I import `QtQuick 1.1` I have:

> Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: declarative

Is there any way to create a Qt Quick applications with static libraries using Qt 5.4?

Comment: How did you build your static Qt? (assuming that you did, because i'm not aware of pre-packageed static builds other than for iOS). It looks like the qtdeclarative or qtquick1 modules weren't included in the build. Add more information about the Qt you use and the .pro file of your project.

Comment: Frank Osterfeld, hello. I built my static version according to this instruction (scroll down to read in english).

Comment: https://bhf.su/threads/40764/?attempt=1

Comment: By building static Qt You loose plugins (QML system consists of multiple plug-in DLLs), which means that these plug-ins have to be compiled into static Qt build in order to work. Build guide that You've provided link to does not compile static Qt with plug-ins. Looking at configuration string used, it looks like pretty much standard Qt configuration which, as You've already understood, does not include QML plug-ins.

Comment: @Mažvydas Tadaravičius thanks for reply. Can u give me correct configuration string please?